# Failed to get remote.origin.url task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configuredwith the 'repo option

Tags: reactjs, git, github, npm

In my weather-app I am using `npm run deploy` command in terminal

But it gives this error:

```
Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! weather_app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the weather_app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pankaj/.npm/_logs/2021-11-22T19_38_21_874Z-debug.log
```

Also I don't know which command should i write to get access to my git repository which is already pushed on my github account...

Comment: I am using currently linux. I uploaded my repository tomorrow reactjs weather-app but today I dont know how to reacces my git repository it show  pankaj   main  ~  Desktop  Projects  weather_app  git remote set-url origin https://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@github.com/SonikeshKumar14/weathr-app.git
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
 pankaj   main  ~  Desktop  Projects  weather_app  128 

Comment: It looks like you created a new repository on your own machine, rather than cloning an existing GitHub repository. That's not a wrong thing to do in Git, but it is (apparently) a wrong thing to do with whatever npm software you're using. In other words, your problem is not Git itself, but some other software's requirements for the way you must use Git.

Comment: You *may* be able to fix this without starting over, using `git remote add`. But this may not be sufficient. A lot depends on the npm software you're using (note that this does not depend on *npm*, which is a package manager, but rather on the *software package you chose*, `weather_app`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue mentioned in the subject and it really wasted a lot of my time but then I figured it out, the probable reasons with me were:
In the terminal, I cd to the folder(my-react-app let's call it folder-A) containing the project files/react app files and when I cloned the git repo of the app to that folder(folder-A), it automatically created another folder inside that folder with the same name as the repo and created a .git and readme file inside it (let's call it folder-B). Then I cd to the folder (folder-B) containing that .git and readme file leaving my project files in the first folder (folder-A). then, when i run npm run deploy, it was showing the error. What i did was, i copied all the project files from folder-A to the folder-B created after running the git clone command (which contained a .git and readme files) and then run npm run deploy in VS code terminal and it worked for me.
After the above process, I have deployed many apps on github pages and i have not faced the subject issue afterward.
Note: I had Git installed and checked, Git path included in the environment variables, remote origin all set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by putting the following commands in the terminal: git init, get remote add origin (copy and paste the url from your github repository here, the parentheses are not needed), and then npm run deploy

Comment: git remote add origin *

Comment: Don't comment on your answer; _edit_ your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the repo again, did `npm run deploy` and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I believe it was because I forgot to run "git init" at the start of development. I just cloned my repository and it sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too...:
Initially I had my project on external hard disk so I made a local copy of my project and tried the "npm run deploy" command again and it worked for me. (Just make sure your remote origin is correct).
I hope this helps.